# If input is set to 0 how can it be removed from the DOM?

Tags: jquery, html-input

I'm pretty new at jQuery. I'm trying to remove divs from the DOM if the value of an input is set to 0. All of the divs have a class called "item", as if they were items in a shopping cart.

Is there a way to remove each div when is set to 0 without a delete button?

```
<div class="item">
  <label for="inputQuantity">Quantity</label>
  <input type="text" id="inputQuantity" placeholder="1">
</div>

<div class="item">
  <label for="inputQuantity">Quantity</label>
  <input type="text" id="inputQuantity" placeholder="1">
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/A9cm7/

Comment: Have you tried anything? I see no attempt in your question or fiddle.

Comment: IDs must be unique for valid HTML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have repeating ID's, get rid of those for a common class:

```
<div class="item">
  <label>Quantity</label>
  <input type="text" class="inputQuantity" placeholder="1">
</div>
```

Then do:

```
$(".item .inputQuantity").blur(function() {
    if (this.value == 0) {
        //remove it
        $(this).closest(".item").remove();
    }
})
```

This will set a `blur` handler on your inputs, and if the `value` is `0` on `blur`, then it'll remove the div.

Comment: Quick note, this will not work with dynamically added elements. For that, use `$(document).on('blur','.item .inputQuantity',function() { ... })`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a freebie since you're new. Next time, please make an effort before posting.

I assume from your question that you want the elements removed on page load, and not as a result of use action.

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/A9cm7/5

```
$(function () {
    $('.item input').each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == '0' || $(this).val() == '') {
            $(this).closest('.item').remove();
        }
    });
});
```

This checks for both '0' and empty values.